# Piping tail -f to cut to sed produces no output

Tags: linux, shell, sed, cut, tail

I try to display a named pipe in a Terminal with this command:

`tail -f textFile | cut -d " " -f 3- | sed -e "s/a/g&g/"`

For some reason this produces no output.

It does work as expected if the -f is removed:

`tail textFile | cut -d " " -f 3- | sed -e "s/a/g&g/"`

or the cut statement is removed:

`tail -f textFile | sed -e "s/a/g&g/"`

or the sed statement is removed:

`tail -f textFile | cut -d " " -f 3-`

Only when all of these three things are there together, it suddenly doesn't produce any output anymore. The order of sed and cut don't make a difference. All of this makes it hard for me to blame the input or output buffering behaviour of any one or pair of these programms.

A possible solution to get the required functionality would be a `while read line` structure, but I would like to avoid initializing a command for every line, if at all possible.

Comment: Provide sample lines from the `textFile`, to investigate why!

Comment: It really doesn't matter. For testing purposes I'm using a text file with the content: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \n bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`

Comment: Can you try the command as `tail -f textFile | while read text; do echo "$text" | cut -d " " -f 3- | sed -e "s/a/g&g/; done `. Because, i guess it is how `tail` and `cut` process their output and input streams respectively I guess! Will post it as an answer if it works

Comment: This works (if you add the missing ") but I already explain why I would rather avoid this solution in my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was experiencing something similar with a ping command that I wanted to filter.

The following webpage seems to explain what the issue is (stdio buffering)
http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

The website points to a solution which involves disabling the buffering with the "stdbuf" command

```
tail -f filename | stdbuf -o0 cut -d " " -f 3- | sed -e "s/a/g&g/"
```

The above works well for me,  and removing "stdbuf -o0" causes no output to be displayed.

```
>stdbuf --help
Usage: stdbuf OPTION... COMMAND
Run COMMAND, with modified buffering operations for its standard streams.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -i, --input=MODE   adjust standard input stream buffering
  -o, --output=MODE  adjust standard output stream buffering
  -e, --error=MODE   adjust standard error stream buffering
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

Comment: The article that you point to mentions using `-oL` for line-oriented throughput (which tail and cut produce, afaik) any reason why you went with `-o0` ?